# How to extend a volume using lvextend command

Tags: centos, out-of-memory, volume, volumes

I am facing a problem related to the resources I have assigned on a machine. I have the following configuration with the volumes.

I have reached the maximum space used on the / path as you can see here:

```
[root@ossx234 tester]# df -h
Filesystem                            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                               16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                  16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                  16G   19M   16G   1% /run
tmpfs                                  16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-root_vol       3.0G  3.0G   36K 100% /
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-home_vol      1014M  387M  628M  39% /home
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-var_vol         80G   74G  6.7G  92% /var
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-tmp_vol        5.0G   34M  5.0G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-var_log_audit 1014M   72M  943M   8% /var/log/audit
/dev/sda1                            509M  200M  310M  40% /boot
```

I would like to extend the volume **/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-root_vol**.

This is my current configuration and as you can see I have more than 6GB left to be assigned.

```
[root@ossx234 tester]# lvmdiskscan   
/dev/sda1 [     512.00 MiB]   /dev/sda2 [     <99.50 GiB] LVM physical volume   
/dev/sdb  [     200.00 GiB]   1 disk   1 partition   0 LVM physical volume whole disks   1 LVM physical volume 

[root@ossx234 tester]# pvs -v   
PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  DevSize 
PV UUID   /dev/sda2  VolGroup00 lvm2 a--  <99.50g <6.52g <99.50g kJn5C1-eydq-h5Bh-pCwh-brq6-ScMS-SVyoZx
```

I tried to extend the volume by executing the command `lvextend -r -L+2G /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-root_vol` and I am getting this error:

```
[root@ossx234 tester]# lvextend -r -L+2G /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-root_vol   
Couldn't create temporary archive name.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix this problem by creating a Physical Volume from the /dev/sdb by executing the following actions:

- `pvcreate /dev/sdb` (to create the Physical Volume)
- `vgs` (to list the current Volume Groups)
- `vgextend VolGroup00 /dev/sdb` (to extend the Volume Group with the Physical Volume created)

Once we have done this steps, we can execute again the command `lvextend -r -L+2G /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-root_vol` to extend the desired volume.